How make white star symbol within black filled circle?
I tried to make the symbols as shown in the picture but it's bigger than the other content. How can I fix it? I would be grateful if anyone could help me in this regard.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm,mathtools}  % Mathematical symbols and environments
\usepackage{tikz} % For drawing boxes
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
% Define the command to circle and fill 
\newcommand{\filledcircled}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]\node[fill=black, text=white, draw, circle, inner sep=0.0pt, minimum size=0.0em, line width=0.0pt] (char) {#1};%
}
%define star
\newcommand\opensmallstar[1][0.1]{%
  \scalerel*{%
    \stackinset{c}{-.125pt}{c}{}{\scalebox{#1}{\color{white}{$\bigstar$}}}{%
      $\bigstar$}%
  }{\bigstar}
}
% Define the custom command
\newcommand{\filledcircledopenbigstar}{\protect\filledcircled{\opensmallstar{}}}
\begin{document}
If $a \text{\filledcircledopenbigstar}b$ is defined as $2 a-b^{a}$, what value is associated with $(5\text{\filledcircledopenbigstar} 2) -(3\text{\filledcircledopenbigstar}2)$?
\end{document}


You can use pifont package: the symbols are \ding{74} and \ding{95}.

A possible MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\blst}{\mathrel{\text{\ding{74}}}}
\newcommand{\cost}{\mathrel{\text{\ding{95}}}}
\begin{document}
If $a \cost b$ is defined as $2a-b^a$, what value is associated with $(5 \cost 2)$ 
$a \blst b$
\end{document}


